# Battery cost LCOE and carbon emission by hourly. Validation of calculation approach

Tags: power, batteries, energy, power-grid

I am compiling a report and trying to validate my understanding of using power correctly to multiply with constants like price and emission in kg weight. Please point out if the  approach below is correct to find the hourly emission and cost of using battery .

**LCOS of battery**

Taking example of Tesla Megapack with a warranty of 15 years (expected lifetime) and a cost of $300/kWh including servicing and maintainance for 15 to 20 years.
"Each Megapack comes from the factory fully-assembled with up to 3 megawatt hours (MWhs) of storage " https://www.tesla.com/en_AU/blog/introducing-megapack-utility-scale-energy-storage

- 15 year's cost of storage = 300 $/kWh
- 1 day's cost of using this storage = 300 ($/kWh) / (15*365) = 0.055 $/kWh

Thus ,1 day's 1 kWh battery cost = $0.055

- 1 day's 100 kWh battery cost = 100 * $0.055 = $5.5
- 1 day's 1 MWh battery cost = 1000 * $0.055 = $55

**LCA Carbon emission of battery**

- 15 year's Battery CO<sub>2</sub> emission = 70 g CO<sub>2</sub>-eq/kWh
- 1 day's CO<sub>2</sub> emission = 70 g CO<sub>2</sub>-eq/kWh / (15*365) = 0.01278 g CO<sub>2</sub>-eq/kWh

Thus, 1 day's 1kWh battery CO<sub>2</sub> footprint = 0.01278 g CO<sub>2</sub> eq

- 1 day's 100 kWh battery CO<sub>2</sub> emission = 100 * 0.01278 = 1.27800 g CO<sub>2</sub> eq
- 1 day's 1 MWh battery CO<sub>2</sub> emission = 1000 * 0.01278 = 12.78 g CO<sub>2</sub> eq

Example :

If CAISO has 220 MWh battery storage systems,   ( given 2018 figure and further appending data from EIA https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/detail.php?id=44696) then

**Cost of CAISO battery storage every hour**

- 1 day's 220 Mwh battery cost = 220 * 55 / 1000 = 12.1 $
- 1 hour's 220 Mwh battery cost =  12.1 / 24 = 0.504 $

**Carbon Emission of CAISO battery storage every hour**

- 1 day's 220 Mwh battery CO<sub>2</sub> emission = 220 * 12.78 /1000 = 2.8116 kg CO<sub>2</sub> eq
- 1 hour's 220 Mwh battery CO<sub>2</sub> emission = 2.8116 /24 = 0.11715 kg CO<sub>2</sub> eq

Comment: It looks like you are mixing up kWh (energy) and kW (power). They are not the same. I can't figure out what you are trying to calculate...can you add some explanation for your equations?

Comment: Hello @ElliotAlderson Yes u are right , I was using 65 MW ( power )  instead maybe is it correct if I use the energy  of battery such as 3Mwh is of 1 tesla megapack and 220 Mwh as a utility scale battery stoarge ? Edited the calculation . please help me to figure out if this one is closer to correctness

Comment: I had done some edits to your post but they seem to have been overwritten by your simultaneous edit. Use `CO<sub>2</sub>` for the subscript and 'W' for watt.

Comment: I am trying to find out the hourly co2 eq emission and cost of using battery by a utility provider . Since I have 5 minute rolling average from http://www.caiso.com/todaysoutlook/pages/supply.aspx ), I have obtainted the hourly battery energy values ( Mwh) by taking a  mean of all 5 minute average values every hour . I  seek some guidance  whether I can multiply this directly by the derieved co2 emission (0.11715 kg Co2 eq/h)  to calculate total emission every hour or not .

Comment: CO2 emissions will depend on the hour of the day too. Are they charging when a lot of solar is on the grid, and discharging when there's more natural gas? That would result in negative emissions. In the opposite scenario, they could be increasing emissions. Five minute emissions data is here: http://www.caiso.com/todaysoutlook/pages/emissions.html

Comment: hello @LShaver yes that is exactly where i took the high granularity datatset . Yes u have an excellenet point . They have negative charging ( denoting discharging ) . Does one take absolute value of charging and discharing energy to be computed for carbon emissions every hour ?